# I can't run Tests using TestNG in selenium using java for automation testing

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, compiler-errors, testng-eclipse

I can't run tests in TestNG, I installed the NG Test eclipse, I added the necessary files and I get an error when I run any test, using TestNG .
Can you tell me a solution to the problem, please?
Thanks!

I installed the necessary files for TestNg, I imported Jar files, and I still receive the same error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.